# How to unit test the catch body of my Observable

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, rxjs, angular-observable

In my `Angular` application, I'm using `Observables` in the following way:

```
getItem(id): Observable<Object> {
  return this.myApi.myMethod(...).catch(e => {
    /* CATCH BODY */
    return Observable.throw(e);
  });
}
```

and I unit test it:

```
it('getItem(...) should correctly do its job',
  inject([MyService], (service: MyService) => {

    const spy = spyOn(myApi, 'myMethod').and.returnValue(mockObservable);

    const mockData = 'mock'; // can be anything
    const mockObservable = Observable.of(mockData);


    service.getItems().subscribe((data) => {
      expect(data).toEqual(mockData);
    });

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...);
  })
);
```

However, I don't know how to unit test the `CATCH BODY`, how can I mock the `observable` to throw an error?

I know similar questions have been asked already, but my case is slightly different and I couldn't succeed in unit testing the catch part.

Comment: You need to mock `myApi` where `myApi.myMethod(...)` sends an error notification.

Comment: yes but how exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another `it` block, and instead of using `Observable.of` use `Observable.throw`, it will create an `Observable` that emits no items and terminates with an error

```
it('getItem(...) should fail',
  inject([MyService], (service: MyService) => {
    const mockData = 'mock'; // can be anything
    const mockObservable = Observable.throw(mockData); // make it fail

    const spy = spyOn(myApi, 'myMethod').and.returnValue(mockObservable);

    service.getItems().subscribe(
        (data) => { 
            // success
        },
        (error) => { 
            expect(error).toEqual(mockData);
        }
    );

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
);
```

Hope it helps